# What does double n mean in tcpdump command?

Tags: tcpdump

The tcpdump manual shows:

```
-n     Don't convert addresses (i.e., host addresses, port numbers, etc.) to names.
```

I have seen double `n` in a tcpdump command:
https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/

```
tcpdump -nnSX port 443
```

What does double n mean in tcpdump command?

Comment: Looks like [it comes from a RedHat specific patch to tcpdump](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/pull/702) that has been rejected upstreams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this depends on the version of tcpdump you are using.

The following reference https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump is a man page to a version which uses "-nn":

> -n
>
> Don't convert host addresses to names. This can be used to avoid DNS
> lookups.
>
> -nn
>
> Don't convert protocol and port numbers etc. to names either.

Thanks,
Deric

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to mean anything of it's own for `tcpdump`, so in this case it's equivalent to a single `n`.

For some networking tools it used to be/is that a single `n` disabled conversion that (might have) required  network traffic (e.g. host name lookups) while two disabled every such conversion (i.e. post numbers are usually converted by looking in `/etc/services`). I don't remember if that was also the case for `tcpdump`, but else it might just be a habbit to use two `n`'s.

But the only way to be sure in any particular case, is to ask whoever wrote the command why they use a double `n`.